# How is the best way to set changing colorscheme to a keybinding

Tags: vim

How is the best way to set changing colorscheme to a keybinding?

Sometimes I find myself needing to change scheme due day and light conditions where a dark scheme doesn't suit.

So by default my colorscheme is seoul256. I thought that I could create an if statement in vimscript bound to d to flip the schemes.

So I created a variable cs = 0 which will default to my darkscheme and on keybinding it will set cs =1 which would cause the light scheme to execute.

However vimmscript doesn't like my variables and am unsure how to reload it after key press.

this is my attempt so far.

```
 map <space>d cs = 1
 cs = 0
 if cs = 0
     colorscheme seoul256
 else
     colorscheme calmar256-light
 endif
```

Comment: You'll "need" that once a day *at most* so... I'm not sure there's a point creating a mapping for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `g:colors_names` to get the name of the current color scheme. Then you can compare it to one of the color scheme names and choose the other if it matches.

```
nnoremap <silent> <space>d :exec 'colorscheme' (g:colors_name ==# 'seoul256') ? 'calmar256-light' : 'seoul256'<CR>
```

---

As for why yours doesn't work. You need to use `let` to assign variables. And you can resource a vim script file with `source <filename>`

Comment: I get an invalid expression error.  E121: Undefined variable: g:colors_name
E15: Invalid expression: (g:colors_name ==# 'seoul256') ? 'calmar256-light' : 'seoul256'

Comment: @sayth have you loaded a color scheme yet? A color scheme must have been loaded before `g:colors_name` will have a value. See `:h g:colors_name`